# All fields are showing in one column when exporting mysql data to excel using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export-to-excel

I have written a simple php script for download excel file which contain some MySQL data fetching by a MySQL query. Data is coming correctly but when I am printing that result in excel file, all fields are coming in the first column of excel file, which is not correct. I want single field in single column. what I am missing in the code. Please If anyone have any idea how to achieve that. Here is my code -

```
include('db_connect.php');
$select = "select `dp_id`,`client_id`,`invester_name`,`pan_no` from 
(SELECT `dp_id` , `client_id` , `invester_name` , `pan_no`
FROM `app_form` union all
SELECT `dp_id`,`client_id`,`first_holder_name`,`first_holder_pan` FROM `response_record`)
tbl order by `dp_id`,`client_id`";

//run mysql query and then count number of fields
$export = mysql_query ( $select ) 
   or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

//create csv header row, to contain table headers 
//with database field names
for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ ) {
$header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . ",";
}

//this is where most of the work is done. 
//Loop through the query results, and create 
 //a row for each
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) ) {
$line = '';
//for each field in the row
foreach( $row as $value ) {
    //if null, create blank field
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ){
        $value = ",";
    }
    //else, assign field value to our data
    else {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . ",";
    }
    //add this field value to our row
    $line .= $value;
}
//trim whitespace from each row
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
//remove all carriage returns from the data
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

$file_name = 'excel_data';
//create a file and send to browser for user to download
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$file_name.".xls");
print "$header\n$data";
exit;
```

Here is the screen shot of excel file which I am getting after running this script-[image]

Comment: Use `;` as seperation character. I don't know if that works for a xls file but else you can try a csv file.

Comment: #1 You're creating a CSV file, not an Excel BIFF-format (.xls) file. #2 Use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to create CSV files #3 The separator you need to use is locale-specific in MS Excel, try using a `;` rather than a `,`

Comment: @S.Pols - OP ___is___ generating a csv file, not an xls file.... just because the extension is .xls doesn't mean that the file format is automagically converted to BIFF

Comment: so how can I generate a excel file.Please suggest me changes for that

Comment: You can use [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace following part of your code:

```
foreach( $row as $value ) {
    //if null, create blank field
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ){
        $value = ",";
    }
    //else, assign field value to our data
    else {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . ",";
    }
    //add this field value to our row
    $line .= $value;
}
```

With :

```
foreach( $row as $value ) {
    //if null, create blank field
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ){
        $value = "\t";
    }
    //else, assign field value to our data
    else {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    //add this field value to our row
    $line .= $value;
}
```

and check it works for me

Comment: So all your code is really doing is replacing a comma (`,`) separator with a tab (`\t`) separator.... why didn't you just say that?

Comment: Still same result buddy..?

Comment: yeah,,,I have made some changes according to you. Now it is working. \t is working, thanks bro..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this change :

```
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$file_name.".csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about create a .csv file? You can use the function `fputcsv()` from PHP to help you. A comma-separated values (CSV) (or character-separated values) file stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain-text form. It is relatively simple to use and works great with Excel.

As an example of code, you could do this:

```
<?php

// The data that comes from your MySQL database
$list = array (
    array('ID', 'NAME', 'SALARY'),
    array('123', 'John Doe', '10000'),
    array('456', 'Sara Parker', '12000')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w'); // Your .csv file

// Inserting data in your file using the pointer created above
foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

References:

fputcsv() - 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

The Comma Separated Value (CSV) File Format - 
http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm

Comment: I know this is very simple method but I really need excel file directly from the browser.