# Showing all fields in one excel column

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

I am using the following code to export MySQL query to excel. After downloading the excel sheet, I got error message when I open
"the file format and the extension don't format. the file could be corrupted or unsafe"

If I open it, I will get all fields of same record in one row, (even i am using the `\t` separator between the fields as shown in the code).
if i use in excel text to column the the separator is tab, then all data are separated correctly.

if I use comma in code as separator instead of `\t` ... then it will work fine

```
<?php
$excel_query = unserialize($_SESSION['correspondence_cvs_query']);
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $excel_query);
function cleanData(&$str)
{
$str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: what you are exporting is a CSV file, not xls. Can you open the file with a text editor?

Comment: yes, i can open in text editor. for exporting to CSV i used the another function: fputcsv. I have seen this code in many questions. I have been searching for this for more than 2 weeks

Comment: so you are not really building xls, but CSV. Now, what is the expected output you want?

Comment: I mean, to export to CSV, I used another code. I used fputcsv. Now I want to export to xls, I searched and I found the above code. If it is not the right way to do, please advise

Comment: as I mentioned, the above code does not create a .xls valid file, it creates a CSV file, which is recognized by Excel software as a CSV file...
There are other libraries for creating true .xls file ( check out https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ for example, but it will be more complex than the example above..). I still do not know what your exact goal is for an output file, so I cannot advise further

Answer (score 0):

Keep the content-type header the way you have it, but change the attachment file name.

Use a file name that ends with .csv for comma delimited.  Use .txt for tab-delimited.  When Excel sees the file name extension, it will know how to parse the file.

The .xls extension confuses Excel.  If you use a file name that ends with .xls, the file should be in the Excel proprietary file format, which I doubt you can easily recreate.

Comment: i have searched too much, many users in stackoverflow do the same. even one got the same problem here in the following link: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249330/all-fields-are-showing-in-one-column-when-exporting-mysql-data-to-excel-using-ph). the difference is that i got the opposite situation, he were using comma and solve it by using \t, now i am using \t i got the problem, if i use coma it is working

Comment: Moreover, please note if I use  \t and I did not import the data from Mysql, for instance from array, everything working fine